# Como escrever um módulo python a partir de um teste?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, classes, testes

Estou fazendo um exercício inverso sobre módulos e testes em Python com pytest, mas não estou obtendo sucesso. Sempre que rodo o código recebo a mensagem "E    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'
".

No caso, eu devo escrever o código necessário para que o teste funcione e não o contrário.

Tenho um arquivo de teste chamado "test_google_driver.py", que foi dado e um arquivo com o módulo que será testado por esse teste, o "google_driver.py", que eu criei para tentar fazer o módulo que será testado.

```
#arquivo test_google_driver.py

from google_driver import GoogleDriver

def test_requests():
    result = GoogleDriver().search("test")
    assert 200 == result.status_code
    assert "test" in str(result.content)
```

arquivo google_driver.py

```
class GoogleDriver():

    def __init__(self):
        self.result = "test"

    def search(self, string):
        return self.result

    @property
    def status_code(self):
        return self.__status_code

    @status_code.setter
    def status_code(self, integer):
        self.status_code = 200

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self.__content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, string):
        self.content = "test"
```

Pelo código do teste que foi dado entendo que preciso criar a classe GoogleDriver, a qual terá o método search que recebe o parâmetro de uma string e retorna um objeto result; e as propriedades status_code (que deve ter um valor de 200) e content (que deve ter uma string também).

Como posso fazer meu módulo funcionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível obter este resultado de diversas maneiras, esta aqui é uma delas. Começando pelo desenho da classe, ou melhor, classes:

```py
""" GoogleDriver.py """

class GoogleDriver: 
    """ The GoogleDriver ^_^ """ 

    @staticmethod 
    def search(string): 
        """ dummy static method... """ 
        return GoogleDriverResults(string) 


class GoogleDriverResults: 
    """ Search for things """ 

    messages = { 
        "test": "This is a test", 
        "dummy": "It's a dummy message", 
        "dunno": "Put your funny message here", 
    } 

    def __init__(self, search_str): 
        result =  self.messages.get(search_str) 
        if result: 
            self.status_code = 200 
            self.content = result 
        else: 
            self.status_code = 404 
            self.content = "Not found, try again."
```

A classe `GoogleDriver` atua meio que como uma *factory* instanciando a classe correta a partir de um método estático (a presença do `GoogleDriver().search("test")` já denunciou o precisaria ser feito).

Claro que isto é um exemplo e falta bastante recheio nas duas mas o importante é que a a classe `GoogleDriverResults` efetivamente faz uma pesquisa e retorna um resultado "válido"

Daí é possível usar a rotina de testes para obter o resultado esperado...

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.2.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /tmp
collected 1 item                                                               

test_google_driver.py .                                                  [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 1.75s ===============================
```

Comment: muito obrigada, agora sim o teste rodou. Você usou bastante coisas que eu não conheço. Eu ainda sou iniciante nesse estudo. Achei que fosse obrigatório usar o self em todas os métodos da classe.

Comment: Pois é, o uso do `self` é realmente obrigatório mas no caso do _static method_ e também do _class method_ ele será adicionado justamente pelo decorador correspondente (os `@staticmethod`e `@classmethod`, respectivamente).